# Laravel echo and pusher 403 on live environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, pusher

So I currently have an echo + pusher instance running locally. Now, When I deploy this code to my live environments, it breaks.

I always get a 403 error, but it's exactly the same code. I don't get it. I just use the default `Broadcast::routes()`

Locally, I use the echo service on a subdomain (http://sub.domain.local/) and there it works, just fine (auth gets done on tha subdomain).

HOWEVER, I'd like to have the authentication to be on one specific domain (common.domain.local). But if it works, it works...

Now when I deploy this to the live environment, I see in my console `POST https://sub.domain.io/broadcasting/auth 403`...

While the code is exactly the same?

The only difference I can tell that's going on is that there is an SSL cert on the server (let's encrypt), the reset is exactly the same....

Anyone who has any idea?

**Edit**

This is my broadcasting.php config:

```
connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: @KamleshPaul Added!

Comment: and `channels.php` as well

Comment: I don't have any of that? I just use Laravel, with echo and Pusher, like here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#configuration

Comment: read that doc `Authorizing Channels`

Comment: I did read the docs, multiple times... I have been searching for over two days by now to have this issue fixed. The sockets work perfectly locally on my laptop, but when I start using ssl certs on the test environment and live, (thus host on a server), the auth throws a 403

Comment: i think you need to create channel in `chennels.php` and add gurad to that like this `Broadcast::channel( ....,['guards' => 'web'])` then it will know where to authorize

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem as you, here is [my solution](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/92#issuecomment-656594585)

1.configs/broadcasting.php:

```php
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

2.configs/websockets.php

```php
    'ssl' => [

        'local_cert' => env('SSL_CERT', null),

        'local_pk' => env('SSL_PK', null),

        'passphrase' => env('JWT_SECRET', null),

        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
```

3.env

```sh
SSL_CERT=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSL_PK=/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

4.on client side

```js
        window.ECHOR = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'pusher',
            key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
            wsHost: window.location.hostname,
            wsPort: 6001,
            wssPort: 6001,
            disableStats: true,
            enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],

            // I am using jwt, if you are not, ignore this
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `${store.state.auth.token.token_type} ${store.state.auth.token.access_token}`
                }
            }
        });
```

5.make sure you allow 6001 on your server

```sh
sudo ufw allow 6001
```

Comment: Nothing of the above seems to work... I'm using pusher btw

Comment: @KamleshPaul Maybe you can try `return $user` first, to check if errors occured in `channels.php`. Check your chrome console to see whether the ws was connected with ssl

Comment: @Robin I am using [laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) instead of [pusher](https://pusher.com/), but you can still use the npm package of pusher-js. It doesn't limit your amount of ws connects.

Comment: It might help, this is the request that I get a 403 on; https://i.imgur.com/SA2yrFw.png

Comment: @Robin for me, here is a successful auth request https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDLyX.png, and the `channels.php` https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmvlX.png, you can see a wss connect is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1h4M.png

Comment: I know what a successfull wss connection would look like. It's just, the auth works on my local computer (with no ssl) but when I deploy (with forge) on my staging and production server, the auth fails with a 403...